# Blazor server project with SignalR can't work on my IIS Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, signalr, blazor

I'm developing a WebApp in Blazor where i need to use SignalR.
All works (including debugging with visual studio) until i try to test it on IIS, where the page start to loading and never stop.
No error, no timeout to the request, only a blank page and the icon of loading on the browser.
**I've already try the web socket issues on IIS and no changes happened.**
Thanks in advance for yours solutions

Comment: How about you display some code! to better understand what is wrong

Comment: Server side Blazor or Blazor on WebAssembly? You really should use the latter, as the former relies on reliable network connections and is mainly for internal web sites.

Comment: try to set the ideal time out value to 0 in the application pool advance setting. assign iis_iusrs and iusr permission to the site folder. enable WebSockets on IIS.